# Custom HTTP Errors in IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, custom-errors

I'm trying to handle 403 and 404 errors in my web app.  I have read [MS instructions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771076%28WS.10%29.aspx) and applied on my server.  IIS7 manager effectively handles this by editing my web.config as:

```
<httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="/MySite" httpResponseStatus="Temporary" />
   <httpErrors>
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/mySite/Error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
       <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/mySite/Error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
   </httpErrors>
```

It does handle requests like http://www.mysite/fictiousURL.aspx but won't work on http://www.mysite/fictiousURLTest.html.  It seems to only be able to handle aspx requests.

I've also tried http://www.15seconds.com/issue/030102.htm by adding this configuration `<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/mysite/error.aspx" />` in the system.web node.

Anyone know a)  Why is IIS7 only handling the aspx and b)  Anyone know how to handle universal requsts like http://www.mysite/fictiousURLTest.html?

Thanks, Bill N

Answer (score 2):

See my response given here:  [IIS7 and HTTP status code handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833834/iis7-and-http-status-code-handling)

It looks like you may need to set

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
```